# xil_cache error in Xilinx SDK

Tags: fpga, xilinx, xilinx-ise, spartan, xilinx-edk

I am working on a small project of mine on Digilent Atlys and after all of the standard generating  the netlist and bitstream, and exporting to SDK, I happen to get a weird error which states that the `xil_cache.h` is not present anywhere (even though it is there).

I need to mention that if I don't add an interrupt controller and a timer it works, but I really do need them.

Has anyone encountered this error before?

---

***Error Message:***

```
08:24:21 **** Build of configuration Debug for project hiworld ****
make all 
'Building file: ../src/helloworld.c'
'Invoking: MicroBlaze gcc compiler'
mb-gcc -Wall -O0 -g3 -c -fmessage-length=0 -I../../hiworld_bsp/microblaze_0/include -mlittle-endian -mxl-barrel-shift -mxl-pattern-compare -mcpu=v8.50.c -mno-xl-soft-mul -Wl,--no-relax -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -MP -MF"src/helloworld.d" -MT"src/helloworld.d" -o "src/helloworld.o" "../src/helloworld.c"
'Finished building: ../src/helloworld.c'
' '
'Building file: ../src/platform.c'
'Invoking: MicroBlaze gcc compiler'
mb-gcc -Wall -O0 -g3 -c -fmessage-length=0 -I../../hiworld_bsp/microblaze_0/include -mlittle-endian -mxl-barrel-shift -mxl-pattern-compare -mcpu=v8.50.c -mno-xl-soft-mul -Wl,--no-relax -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -MMD -MP -MF"src/platform.d" -MT"src/platform.d" -o "src/platform.o" "../src/platform.c"
../src/platform.c:43:23: fatal error: xil_cache.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [src/platform.o] Error 1

08:24:21 Build Finished (took 734ms)
```

Comment: What about the other library? Are they present? Just to try to find a solution: comment all the line related with the cache (library and code). DO you have other errors?

Comment: No other errors really - just this singular one. Also bear in mind that the error occurs after the SDK files are generated, thus I had not done anything bad.

Comment: Share your code and your error message: every thing that gives us the possibility to replicate the same error

Comment: I reverted to an older version of my project which does not have the said problem. Once the error occur again I will post it here.

Comment: Updated with the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try after setting below environmental variables:

```
XILINX = C:\Xilinx\14.5\ISE_DS
XILINX_EDK = C:\Xilinx\14.5\ISE_DS\EDK\bin\nt64
```

this is suggested in the Xilinx forum and seems to solve the problem.

A user writes:

"Magic :-)

I created a batch file to launch it, as from what I know the path variables persit within that batch file

I set it to

```
set path=""
XILINX = C:\Xilinx\14.5\ISE_DS
XILINX_EDK = C:\Xilinx\14.5\ISE_DS\EDK\bin\nt64
C:\Xilinx\14.5\ISE_DS\EDK\bin\nt64\xsdk.exe
```

Interesting the shortcut to the SDK first contains a link to settings64.bat which I assumed set all these variables correctly, but it looks like it doesnt get them right!

I have to admit its been a trek just getting this far as the documentation is a bit blurry."

[Here](https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Spartan-Family-FPGAs/xil-cache-h-No-such-file-or-directory/td-p/420693) you can find the page.

Comment: do you have Windows, Linux or something else?

Comment: Currently I am on Windows, but soon I shall (with the project) be migrating to a Linux machine.